# Show HTML5 video poster on pause

Tags: html, html5-video

Is it possible display a video's poster attribute on pause, rather then the current frame of the video?

Comment: You may listen to `pause` event to put up an `<img>` element over that video, and listen to `play` event to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a method that doesn't need extra markup.

On pause event, add this:

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var pauseTime = mediaElement.currentTime;
mediaElement.load();
```

Basically, the load method reloads the video so your poster is visible again.

On play event:

```
mediaElement.currentTime = pauseTime;
mediaElement.play();
```

Note that the pauseTime variable needs to be within scope or passed as parameter to the pause/play event listener functions.

Comment: Reloading the video messes up the buffer events if you have custom controls.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Whenever I pause it just flashes the first frame and then keeps playing